# Multiple nth Child statements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to have a certain set of nth child sequences.

I want to apply a certain styling for the first 10 events, but after the first 10, for every 15 events I want to apply another style.

I tried 2 nth-child statements but I haven't figured it out yet

```
&:nth-child(10n) {color:red;page-break-after:always;}
&:nth-child(10n+15) {color:blue;page-break-after:always;}
```

[image]

I updated the code a bit to make it more clear, and added a picture.

Comment: Is that how you want it to look?

Comment: Yes, mostly with the page breaks, its fine if they're broken vertically as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want every 15th element *after* the 10th to be blue? So the first blue element would be the 25th? Then the 40th, 55th etc.

The thing is, `10n + 15` doesn't do that.

```
10 * 1 + 15 = 25 // right
10 * 2 + 15 = 35 // wrong
10 * 3 + 15 = 45 // wrong
```

Sounds like you want `15n + 10`:

```
15 * 1 + 10 = 25 // right
15 * 2 + 10 = 40 // right
15 * 3 + 10 = 55 // right
```

So the actual selector would be:

```
div:nth-child(15n + 10) {
    color: blue;
}
```

Unfortunately this will also select the 10th element. And I'm assuming you want `blue` to override `red` wherever applicable, except for the 10th element which shouldn't match. So you need to add another selector to reset the 10th element.

```
div:nth-child(10) {
    color: red;
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mvdzc99b/

**EDIT**

The requirements have changed, but I will leave the original information here for reference.

To select *all* of the first 10 you can use `-n+10`. However to select the next 15 is a bit more tricky. You need to use a range from 11 to 25, which is done by combining 2 `:nth-child()` selectors:

```
:nth-child(n+11):nth-child(-n+25) { ... }
```

The next 15 would be

```
:nth-child(n+26):nth-child(-n+40) { ... }
```

You get the picture.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mvdzc99b/3/

```css
div {
    margin: 2px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: black;
    float: left;
}

div:nth-child(-n+10) {
    background: red;
}

div:nth-child(n+11):nth-child(-n+25) {
    background: blue;
}

div:nth-child(n+26):nth-child(-n+40) {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Instead of doing them 1 at a time, I need a chunk of these, check my edit update.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/x63cg1jt/)**

css

```
div{
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    margin:1px;
    display:inline-block
}
div{
    background:black;
}
div:nth-child(10n){
    background:red;
}
div:nth-child(10n + 115){
    background:green;
}
div:nth-child(10n + 110){
    background:black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try and study the below example.

```css
li {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px #333;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 5px;
}


li:nth-of-type(-n+10) {
    background-color: red;

}

li:nth-of-type(n+15) {
    background-color: blue;

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>

  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>

  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>

  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>

  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>

  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>

  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>

  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>

  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>

  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>

</ul>
```